# How do you call husband's brother-in-law?

Tags: kinship-terms

I did some search online but couldn't find an answer, How do you call husband's brother-in-law?

Comment: Your husband's brother-in-law could be ***your*** brother! Or  his sister's husband. Anglophones don't tend to care much about such things, so we don't mind using the same expression for both those relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> Your husband's brother-in-law could be ***your*** brother! Or  his sister's husband. Anglophones don't tend to care much about such things, so we don't mind using the same expression for both those relationships.

To clarify: if the husband’s brother-in-law is your own brother, then you call him whatever you’ve always called him (and refer to him as your brother).

If he’s your husband’s sibling’s husband, then you **don’t** refer to him as your brother. There’s no preciser word than ‘husband’s brother-in-law’ for that in English.

Comment: Noting [*cohabiting couple (not "officially" married) families are the second largest family type, and the fastest growing*](https://www.familylaw.co.uk/news_and_comment/ons-statistics-show-cohabiting-couple-families-are-on-the-rise#.WzI-ntIzqUk), on a page that also says such households *more than doubled from 1.5 million in 1996 to 3.3 million in 2017*, I imagine the *actual* usage is even more flexible than some nns might suppose. I have a divorced friend who calls his ***ex-** inlaws* the ***outlaws***, but actually that might be more suitable for *"related" by cohabitation, not marriage*.